# Azure Restrict ip to the Point to site VPN

Tags: azure, vpn, network-security-groups

I've recently configured a point to site vpn on azure.

It's working pretty well on the client and root certificate principle.

My concern is more on the security side. Would it be possible to restrict the usage of the vpn only to some ips ? For example, there are sometimes, even if people have the client certificate for any reasons, I don't want them to be able to access the azure network from another location.

The security groups come after the vpn. Due to the way the vpn is working, the ip the user will have will be the ip assigned by Azure so I can't restrict by his origin.

Thank you !

Comment: you can restrict network usage or access through ACL, but that also comes after VPN only so there seems no other way in achieving this for additional security you can try MFA.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported solution but you can apply an in-bound NSG rule to the gateway subnet that allows 443, 500 and 4500 from the IPs that you want to allow connection from and block the rest. You have to be very careful not to block any outbound ports or any other ports as that may break the management plane for the VPN Gateway.

Other option is to configure a RADIUS server and configure the appropriate policies on it and point the VPN Gateway to it.